# RapidMiner Java could not be launched - Error 1

Tags: java, rapidminer

I have installed RapidMiner and when i am trying to launch the application, i get

**Java could not be launched  Error 1**

After researching, i have found that running the .bat file could give a more detailed error message which is:

SEVERE: Failed to read RM preferences for user specified license settings (As shown in the picture)

[image: Detailed Error]

System Language is Greek (i am not sure if this is the problem with the path)

Any suggestions?

Java Version 21.XX.

Comment: This bug was fixed in RapidMiner version 10.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the solution from the RapidMiner Community post https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/comment/73142/#Comment_73142

> There is a known issue with non-ascii usernames in 10.2 / 10.3.
>
> As a workaround you could point your .RapidMiner folder to another
> directory by adding i.e.
> `-Drapidminer.user-home=C:\.RapidMiner` to line 158 of the `C:\Program Files\RapidMiner\RapidMiner Studio\RapidMiner Studio.bat`
>
> `"%JAVA%" %JVM_OPTIONS% -cp "%RAPIDMINER_HOME%"\lib\* com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
> would change to:
> `"%JAVA%" %JVM_OPTIONS% -Drapidminer.user-home=C:\.RapidMiner -cp "%RAPIDMINER_HOME%"\lib\* com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
>
> Afterwards you would need to start RapidMiner Studio via the .bat file
> until this is fixed.